# Play YouTube content in background ExoPlayer

Tags: android, youtube, exoplayer

I'm building an audio player with ExoPlayer api. I want play youtube videos in the background. Is that possible with ExoPlayer?

Comment: Assume that you are playing a video with screen off! Is it possible?!

Comment: At least you can't publish the app on PlayStore if you try to play a YouTube video in the background. As for ExoPlayer, I don't know.

Comment: your app will likely get banned on play store if you achieve that somehow. Youtube doesn't allow playing it's videos in background

Comment: @Sujith were you able to do so?